# Control (signature) number for data

Tags: php, sql-server, database, validation

I have a question, some might have encountered while working with data. Trying to figure out how to implement "signature" for data passed back and forth to SQL Server via PHP.

For example, I have a sales order that contains dates, numbers, other variables (string), etc.
The idea is that when that data is inserted into SQL, a "signature" is created based on all the variables (around 30-40) and stored in that table. That signature will be sent to the user when user pulls the data. Then, when a user updates that data and sends back to SQL along with the current signature, PHP would compare that current data signature with the one stored in the database and update the data if it matches. if not - the user will get a notification saying something like "the state of the order has been changed, new data available".

This will prevent one user from overwriting the data if that data has been changed by another user while the first user worked on it.

I thought to add "user signature" which is comparatively easy. However it does not resolve the situation when the same user has opened multiple windows with that data and then accidentally tries to submit updates from one window after he already submitted some data from another window. (Some users are old folks and not tech savvy and may have open multiple windows in the browser, you know).
Locking records won't work here as the data has to be accessible by multiple users at any time.

Thank you for your help!

NOTE: If someone is using SQL Server Management Studio, seems like you can add this column only via query. At least I coud not find this option in "design" view.
`ALTER TABLE table_name ADD Version rowversion;`

Comment: Sounds like you are talking about a `ROWVERSION`.

Comment: Thank you Larnu!!!!! Seems like this is exactly what I am looking for! Thank you! RESOLVED!